# console not showing the output file path etc. for source map after enabling source maps (react native)

Tags: react-native

**NOTE: IF SOMETHING MORE EXPLANATION, PLEASE COMMENT.**

i have enabled source maps generation in android/app/build.gradle by this:

```js
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    hermesFlagsRelease: ["-O", "-output-source-map"], // plus whichever flag was required to set this away from default
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--sourcemap-output", "android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle.map"],
]
```

also in android/app/build.gradle:

```js
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);
```

but the console does not seem to show the output as was written in [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/sourcemaps) that it should show after metro build output.

[image: Console output]

i have tried the above steps but there was only generated an intermediates folder which contained these folders and not the one which the documentation was showing in output.

[image: Folder that generated after enabling source maps]